# CSS not getting imported in component

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader, jss

I have the following Test component:

**Test.css**

```
.SomeClass {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**Test.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import './Test.css';

export const Test = () => {
    return (
        <div className={'SomeClass'}>
            hello
        </div>
    );
};
```

Relevant section of **webpack config**:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'style-loader'
    },
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: !isProduction,
        modules: {
          localIdentName: '[local]',
        },
      },
    }],
},
```

The problem is that the styles are not applied. On inspection, the div looks like this:

```
<div class="SomeClass">hello</div>
```

but there is no "SomeClass" css.

I suspect it is to do with some webpack config. I tried this too: `use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']` instead of the above `use` array, but no luck.

**Edit**

This project uses [react-jss](https://cssinjs.org/react-jss).

Comment: In your index.html file, are you setting up the link ? You're supposed to load the styles.css there.

Comment: No, there is no such line in index.html. This project uses JSS, so I think that is supposed to set this up. So I need to tell JSS somehow to scan for CSS files instead of webpack?